# Does draw_networkx() compute the layout for the entire graph when a nodelist is passed?

Tags: python, networkx

I'm trying to visualize 100 nodes with the highest degrees in a graph that has a total of ~1.5M nodes. I'm using `draw_networkx()` without explicitly passing any value for `pos`; I'm okay with the default spring layout positioning. This is taking a long time and I was wondering if `draw_networks()` computes the layout for the entire graph and then plots the nodes specified in `nodelist`? Is there anyway to optimize this?

I'm using a pandas data frame to generate the graph via `from_pandas_edgelist()`

Code below:

```
nodes = dict(G.degree)
top_100 = sorted(nodes, key=nodes.get, reverse=True)[:100]
nodes_100 = {k: nodes[k] for k in top_100}

plt.figure()
nx.draw_networkx(
    G, 
    node_list=nodes_100.keys(), 
    node_size=nodes_100.values(), 
    with_labels=False, 
    edge_color='grey', 
    linewidth=2
)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

Here is the command within `draw_networkx`:

```
if pos is None:
    pos = nx.drawing.spring_layout(G)
```

So if you don't specify `pos` as an input, it will call `spring_layout` which will find positions of all nodes.

Comment: Thank you! I tried plotting the top 100 nodes and succeeded. I'm working on optimizing the graph to show all the children nodes of the top 100 which is still taking a lot of time to run (this maybe my personal computation resources too).